# Link to images(thumb) in a (block)view to the image(original) in another (page)view

Tags: 7, views

I have a  unlimited multivalue field image gallery.

Using views i created a page for file entity and got the list of files in the field. The page displays the default original images one by one with a pager.

Created a block for the same view with the files shown as thumbnails, so the user can view all images in the gallery and click on the image he/she wants to see. I can link the thumbnails to content or file which takes me to the original file.

Is it possible i can link them to the corresponding image in the page view.

Answer (score 1):

In your block view, if the "Link image to " option doesn't give you what you need for the thumbnail image field, you can build your own link using "Rewrite Results". You would do something like this:

1. Add content:path or nid to your view, and exclude from display
2. Make sure content:path or nid is first in you list of fields
3. For the thumbnail image field, enable "Output this field as a link " under Rewrite Results
4. use the token for nid or content:path (i.e. [path]) to construct the link you need

Note: if you use content:path, you will probably want to enable "Use absolute path" for it's field settings, even though it is excluded from display.

Comment: Hey Dave, Thanks for your time. The view is a list of files not content so i'm not getting nid or content:path only file:path also i want the image file in the block view to link to the image file in the page view. Basically am looking to create a gallery like imdb site.[Ref here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0429493/mediaindex).

Comment: Right. You did mention that these were file entities, and I also somehow missed the views and pager part :) I'm not sure this would be a good solution, but assuming both views show the same content in the same order, then you could add a counter to the block view and construct a link (using rewrite results) to the paged view, something like: viewpath/?page=[counter].

Comment: No luck..looks i need to learn more about file entities. For now am going with nodes like you answered. Giving a vote up. :) Thanks.